# because input does not work when executed in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

my intention is to execute an input N number of times by using a for loop. However, the code I wrote doesn't behave the way I expect it to.

Here I share my code:

```
N, K = map(int, input().split())

values ​​= (list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(N))
print(values)
```

When I execute the code the program ends without executing the inputs. Also, when I try to print the output, I get the following output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001D040ED03C0>
```

Here is a sample of how the program should work:

SampleInput

```
3 1000
2 5 4
3 7 8 9
5 5 7 8 9 10
```

in this case, N would be equal to 3, therefore 3 inputs should be executed

Comment: If your intention is to use a `for` loop, shouldn't there be a `for` loop somewhere in your code?

Comment: `values ​​= [list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(N)]`, using `( ...)` create generator expresion

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you expect out of the program? Like, give us a sample of the user input and then what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: If you want `values` as a list, instead of generator expression use list comprehension

Comment: do you really want to enter multiple numbers N times or just one number N times? Do you need the `split` in the second line? It may be clearer if you show your expected output for a given set of inputs.

Comment: @PaulRooney I already added the changes you suggested, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your code like this

```
values ​​= [list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(N)]
```

Instead of list comprehension, you can for in values like this

```
for i in values:
    print(i)
```